# Is alternating sum of reciprocal of primes absolutely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I remember reading that alternating harmonic function is a conditionally convergent series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}+...$$ 
I wonder, whether alternating sum of reciprocals of primes is also a conditionally convergent series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_n} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7}+...$$ 
If it is, how do we prove it?

Comment: Both sums are not absolutely convergent. But the sum of the reciprocals of the primes grows extremely slow !

Comment: If the signs alternate and the magnitudes decline towards $0$ then the series conditionally converges.  Just consider the partial sums after an odd number of terms and after an even number of terms

Comment: It is known that $\sum_{p\le x}\frac{1}{p}\sim\log\log x$.

Comment: @Henry Usually "conditionally convergent" implies that there is no absolute convergence.

Comment: How do we even proof that both series are conditionally convergent. Because, I think for sure that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (- \frac{1}{2})^{n+1}$$ is absolutely convergent

Comment: See for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test .